# sending a command to heroku console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cedar

What's the correct way of sending a command to heroku console on Cedar?

`heroku console 2+2` works on older stacks - it warns me to use `heroku run console` on cedar.

When I run

`heroku run console 2+2`

it loads the unwanted `"2+2"` environment and opens up a console.

```
Loading 2+2 environment (Rails 3.2.3)
irb(main):001:0>
```

So what's the proper way of sending a command to heroku console on Cedar?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the prettiest solution, but piping the command in did work.

```
echo "2 + 2" | heroku run console
```

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/run.rb), it appears there is no (current) built in way to do it.

Comment: yeah, couldn't find it either. there is no other workaround? when I execute this, I can't exit the console normally and I have to stop the process. thanks for your answer

Comment: I think you may be able to run a detached console with `heroku run:detached console` but I'm not 100% sure.